# Can't use static variables from public class in if()

Tags: c#, mono, rider

First off, I'm completely new in C#!

I need to get a specific console input and I need to have the variable in another class. So I have my `Monster.cs` and my `Program.cs` source files.

So this works (only `Program.cs`):

```
        string race = Console.ReadLine();

        if (race == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Typed 1");
        }
        else if (race == "2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Typed 2");
        }
        else if (race == "3")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Typed 3");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Typed something wrong");
        }
```

But why does this not work?

#### Monster.cs

```
namespace ConsoleSimulation
{
  public class Monster
  {
    public string race = Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

#### Program.cs

```
        string race = Console.ReadLine();

    if (Monster.race == "1")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Typed 1");
    }
    else if (Monster.race == "2")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Typed 2");
    }
    else if (Monster.race == "3")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Typed 3");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Typed something wrong");
    }
```

Comment: read about static classes and fields: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several problems with this code. I'm assuming that you wouldn't want the program to constantly read from the Console as it is doing right now whenever the field is used. You would either need to provide a constructor at the start of the class to assign the value of race like so:

`Monster()
{
    this.race = Console.ReadLine();
}`

or you would have to assign it from calling code. In order to do this, and then access its value, you need an instance of the class. You could do this like so:

`Monster newMonster = new Monster();
newMonster.race = Console.ReadLine(); //only if no constructor`

You could then proceed to use the value of race in the given expressions an example being:

`if (newMonster.race == "1"){//code here}`

If, however, you didn't need class specific values for field, i.e. across instances of the class the value does not change, you could as @Backs has suggested, declare race to be a static field like so:

`public static string race;`

You would then not need the `newMonster` instance of the class at all. Instead, you could simply use the following from your calling code.

`Monster.race = Console.ReadLine();
if(Monster.race == "1"){//code here}`

Notice, however that your declaration of string can still not assign it to be `Console.ReadLine()` in the class.